# Android Device is recognized by Android Studio on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have a Huawei U8815 and its not getting recognized on Windows by the Android Studio, I already changed MTP to PTP and didn't worked, but on Mac it works.

And I have a Nexus-7 and it works on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install USB drivers for the device before it can appear in Android Studio. To confirm that the reasons missing drivers, [open device manager](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000833.htm) You would find an entry that requires drivers with a yellow alert/warning icon, something similar to the image below but not exactly this.

[image: Device manager]

Now Install the appropriate USB/ADB driver for the device. Once driver is installed you can view the device in Android studio.

You may either download the drivers from [this link](http://huaweig300.com/huawei-g300-install-a-custom-jelly-bean-ics-rom-from-scratch/install-the-usb-drivers/) or Install [HiSuite](http://download-c.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=13817&siteCode=worldwide) to get the drivers installed.

Comment: I unistalled and disconnect from PC and plug-in again and it didn't re-install like it was the first time and i already tried to update sofware controller and it didn't find an update.

On devide manager show a danger sign with a "!" inside until the word "Android"

Comment: So this is it . You need the drivers. Try the drivers listed here. http://huaweig300.com/huawei-g300-install-a-custom-jelly-bean-ics-rom-from-scratch/install-the-usb-drivers/

Comment: @TiagoSousa the safest way would be to install huwawei HISUITE  http://download-c.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=13817&siteCode=worldwide This will install the drivers automatically and should be free from any malware or viruses as is provided by huawei  it self

Comment: Sdd this link to your comment http://huaweig300.com/huawei-g300-install-a-custom-jelly-bean-ics-rom-from-scratch/install-the-usb-drivers/

I downloaded from there and on the end of the installation and tried if it was recognized on Android Studio and it work. I only installed that. Thanks

Comment: Add that links to your main post for i can confirm that is the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to download official drivers of the device..and then you are done :) cheers